# Given the motion of a particle, find s'(t) and find when the velocity is zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The motion of  particle is given as $s(t) = A*\cos(\omega t + \delta)$

a) Find the velocity of a particle at time $t$

I know that velocity is $s'(t)$, so I found the derivative using the chain and product rules to be:
$-A*\sin(\omega t + \delta)*\omega+t+1$ although I'm not sure if that is correct.

b) Find when the velocity is zero (use "$n$" as an arbitrary integer)

I thought that to the find when the velocity is zero you would set the derivative equal to $0$ and solve for $t$, but I got as far as $t*\sin(\omega t + \delta)=(-1-\omega)/(-A)$

I don't know what to do next, or even if what I did was correct. Please help!

Comment: Your derivative is wrong.  Where come from the terms $t+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$s(t) = A\cos(\omega t + \delta)$$

$$\frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}t}\cos(\omega t + \delta) + A\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\cos(\omega t + \delta)$$

If $A$ is a constant then the time derivative is zero and you simply get

$$\boxed{v(t) = \dot s(t) = -A\omega\sin(\omega t + \delta)}$$

The velocity is zero when:

- $\omega = 0$ (quite meaningless)
- $A = 0$ (quite meaningless)
- $\sin(\omega t + \delta) = 0$

The last case is the meaningful one, and it's solved for

$$\omega t + \delta =  n\pi ~~~~~~~~~~~ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Hence

$$t = \frac{n\pi - \delta}{\omega}$$

in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the chain rule you took care of the $(\omega t + \delta)$ which gave you that factor of $\omega$.  Where in the world did the $t+1 come from?

With that $t+1$ gone the second half of the question becomes a lot easier!